# Data Model for employee holiday management system

Tags: database-design, analysis, modeling

I'm working on an employee holiday management system and need advise on how to efficiently model the data.

Is there any example or references somewhere that I could learn from.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very specific question, so I can not recommend any specific tools for the task.

Take  alook here (called Data modeling 101) http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataModeling101.html

Some example diagrams for departments and staff http://www.laynetworks.com/DBMS.htm

Also you might want to read up on normalization of databases http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Thank you for those. very good useful links. But I was hoping to find an example model or schema for holidays